# input - loop calling vector elements / error ValueError

Tags: python, loops, vector

I am trying to write a simple program which in a loop with input takes successive elements of the vector until the letter E is typed.

for example: gives 1,2,3,4, E - after entering E the program ends, but but after always typing the letter E, the program doesn't exit but crashes the error

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: 'E'", how can I fix it,

what am I doing wrong?

```
class Vector:
    
    def elements(self):
        v = []
        n = int(input("Enter elements: "))
        for i in range(0, n):
            element = int(input())
            v.append(element)
            if element == 'E':
                break
            print(v)
```

Comment: Why breaking on `E` as you have already defined an amount of values ?

Comment: you take input directly instead of just acceptiing int and your program donot end beacause you are taking int input and 'E' is a str , So change line 
element = int(input()) --> element = input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your taking an int input, therefor you can't enter `E`. Instead take a string input.

```
element = input()
if element == 'E':
    break
v.append(int(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the input is `E`, if yes, `break`, otherwise convert to `int`:

```
class Vector:
    
    def elements(self):
        v = []
        n = int(input("Enter elements: "))
        for i in range(0, n):
            element = input()
            if element == 'E':
                break
            v.append(int(element))
            print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first save the input as a `str`, and convert to `int` after the `E` verification. But I don't get why you use the `E` breaking, as you already use a choosen amount of values to enter

```
def elements(self):
    v = []
    n = int(input("How many elements: "))
    for i in range(n):
        element = input(f"Enter element n°{i + 1}/{n}: ")
        if element == 'E':
            break
        v.append(int(element))
        print(v)
```